# Why is my Django custom form field's to_python() not working?

Tags: django

Fairly new to Django and I've been struggling with this problem for a bit now.

I'm trying to create a custom form field that inherits from CharField. I want it to process input from a form so that double spaces in strings are replaced with single spaces. However, it seems that the custom form's to_python() is never called because whenever I input something like `'a  a'` in the form, the double spaces still make it through to the database. I've also noticed that the input is properly stripped as if CharField.to_python is still being called.

My understanding is that to_python() is called whenever form.is_valid() is called. I'm not sure if I've done that properly in the form view.

Here is the custom field:

```
class NameField(forms.CharField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        """ Remove extra spaces in input. """

        if value not in self.empty_values:
            value = str(value)

            if self.strip:
                value = value.strip()

            if '  ' in value:
                value = value.replace('  ', ' ')

        if value in self.empty_values:
            return self.empty_value

        return value
```

The form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):

    name = NameField()
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    cost = forms.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)],
    )
    _quality = models.DecimalField(
        blank=True,
        default=0.0,
        max_digits=2,
        decimal_places=1,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(5.0)]
    )
```

And the view:

```
def form(request):

    product_form_set = modelformset_factory(
        Product,
        fields=('name', 'quantity', 'cost')
    )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = product_form_set(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

    else:
        formset = product_form_set()

    return render(request, 'synergy/form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your field. It's just that you're not using your `ProductForm` anywhere, so I don't really see why you expect your `NameField` to be used. Also, when you use it in your formset, it should be a `ModelForm`, not just a `Form`